# could not run this unit test with mock

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I tried to make an unit test for this method which is pretty simple only add an object into the data base and if it works well returns true

```
Public Shared Function CrearCliente(ByVal cliente As Cliente) As Boolean
    Try
        db.Cliente.Add(cliente)
        db.SaveChanges()
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception("ocurrio un error guardando al cliente")
    End Try
End Function
```

Now here's my test

```
<TestMethod()>
Public Sub CrearClienteTest()
    Dim mock = New Moq.Mock(Of Cliente)
    Dim actual As Boolean
    mock.Setup(Function(x) x.Nombre).Returns("blah")
    'mock.Setup(Function(x) x.Apellido()
    actual = Class1.CrearCliente(mock.Object)
    Assert.AreEqual(True, actual)
End Sub
```

Pretty easy my question is why when Debugged the test throws this error

```
Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: x => x.Nombre
```

What could be wrong? do i need another configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states, Moq requires that the member you mock be `Overridable`.